# Submit update of iphone client

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Customer has iPhone app on appstore. Second version of this app was developed from the beginning. Now, when I install appstore version and install new one from xcode it crashes with error:

> [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   usernameTextField.'

What is appropriate way to submit update in this situation

UPDT

We dont have usernameTextField in new version

Comment: Oh dear. Looks like you've broken it. Seeing as you've got all the source code in front of you and all of the debugging tools available to you and you can't find the problem, how are you expecting us to help you when we have no of that available to us?

Comment: If you could explain better, would be good for people to answer it

Answer (score 2):

This is almost always a case of removing an outlet from the code and not removing it from all the places it was used in the storyboard or xib files.  Look through those and delete references to that outlet's name.  If they don't show up in the graphical editor, use Open As...->Source Code and search the text for `usernameTextField`.

Comment: It used in previous version of xib named LoginView.xib. In new version we have LoginViewController.xib. and our LoginViewController.h doesn't have usernameTextField.

Comment: It's a good bet that either the name is referenced in your new xib or an old xib is being included in your build and is being loaded.  As I suggested, search through the source code of you xib files.

Comment: In new project we dont't have this aotlet and this xib at all

Comment: When it gives you the error and says **this class**, does it also tell you the name of the class that it's complaining about?

Comment: Frankly, this is a better answer than mine. More cases are covered.

Comment: To Phillip: yes, LoginViewController. But I don't know why it loads LoginView.xib but not LoginViewController.xib

Comment: I know I'm repeating myself and it's probably frustrating for you but have you actually opened a text view of LoginViewController.xib and searched for the string `usernameTextField`?  Call it tunnel vision if you like but I'd like to be absolutely sure that the most common cause of this is not true before considering others.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application was not updated correctly and files from the old version are still present. Do a clean build (i.e. Clean, then Build) of your app and the problem should self-correct.

Comment: Is there some flags to delete files from previous version, if they are not presented in new one?

Comment: Nope. Your new application shoud not care about leftover files.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by renaming my AppDeligate with name used in previous version